# how to handle response from bank message in bale bot?

Tags: bale-messenger, balebot

we need a solution to handle the response of purchase message that has succeeded?

for example, when purchase message paid to go ok we how to handle the conversation?

`from balebot.filters.bank_message_filter import BankMessageFilter`

```
 class BankMessageFilter(Filter):
    def match(self, message):
        return isinstance(message, BankMessage)
```

and here: `BankMessageFilter`

and then check the message received from transaction bot for check correctness of transaction payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic python BankMessage handler. Consider the following:

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(PhotoFilter())
def purchase_message(bot, update):
    message = update.get_effective_message()
    user_peer = update.get_effective_user()
    first_purchase_message = PurchaseMessage(msg=message, account_number=6037991067471130, amount=100,
                                             money_request_type=MoneyRequestType.normal)
    bot.send_message(first_purchase_message, user_peer, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)
    dispatcher.register_conversation_next_step_handler(update, [MessageHandler(BankMessageFilter(), payment),
                                                                MessageHandler(DefaultFilter(), default_handler)])


def payment(bot, update):
    message = update.get_effective_message()
    print("message:", message)
    success_payment = TextMessage("Thanks, your payment was successful")
    bot.reply(update, success_payment, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)
    dispatcher.finish_conversation(update)
```

BankMessageFilter has defined in balebot python library.